# Flutter WidgetsBindingObserver on Android behave differently from IOS

Tags: flutter

I am using WidgetsBindingObserver to check the platform brightness, it works well when the app is up and running. The app can detect the platform brightness changes by user. However when the app is closed and reopen again. The initial startup the method "didChangePlatformBrightness()" did not run at all for Android but it was executed for IOS. Why is this so?

Below is my code:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver{

  ScaffoldDataBloc bloc;
  ScaffoldDataState state;

  var systemBrightness;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    bloc = ScaffoldDataBloc();
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    super.didChangePlatformBrightness();
    final Brightness brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
    //inform listeners and rebuild widget tree

    systemBrightness = brightness;
    print('didchange: ' + systemBrightness.toString());
    setState(() {});
  }

....
```

On Android, the print statement 'didchange' was not printout. For IOS this is the result:

flutter: didchange: Brightness.dark

Is it a bug?

Thanks.